# Custom Label Deployment using outbound Change Set

Tags: deployment, change-set, customlabel

I created a Change Set and added about 15 components, including 4 custom labels
The Custom Labels did not get deployed, I don't see these in the destination org.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the error?